# Adicionar layouts dinamicamente

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Criei um XML com o LinearLayout, nele eu tenho um Spinner e um EditText. Na minha tela eu tenho um LinearLayout que deve receber esse outro layout que criei.

Minha dúvida é: como adicionar esse layout customizado na minha tela dentro do outro layout?

Já tentei usar o findById para pegar o layout customizado, mas retorna null.

Toda vez que clicar em um botão eu devo adicionar o layout customizado dentro do linear que está na minha tela.

Como devo fazer?

Comment: Seria mais prático adicionares o código relevante à pergunta de forma a que se possa facultar uma resposta que vá de encontro com a resolução do teu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou supondo que este XML que você citou é o que você está querendo adicionar em sua tela dinamicamente, certo?

Assim sendo, você vai obter esta `View`, supondo ser o layout `qualquer.xml`, assim:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.qualquer, null);
```

E em seguida, adicionar em sua tela, por exemplo, dentro do elemento `foo`:

```
LinearLayout foo = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.foo);
foo.addView(view);
```

Verifique se está de acordo com o que você precisa.

Comment: Ótimo! Obrigado.