# Adicionar novas views dinamicamente

Tags: android, android-layout

Possuo uma activity que contém o cardView da imagem a ao fim da pergunta que possui 3 edittext.
Queria saber como posso fazer para que quando clicar em algum botão, um novo cardview com o mesmo layout seja adicionado novamente, para que eu possa recuperar seus dados. Tentei seguir o indicado nesta outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7885/adicionar-layouts-dinamicamente), porém não obtive sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cardview fica dentro de um outro RelativeLayout e seu layout é o seguinte:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/infoContato"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/infoCadastro"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tituloInfoContato"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewIcTelefone"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dicaTelefone"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewIcTelefone"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcTelefone"
            android:text="@string/lblInfoContato"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Telefone -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInputAddCadastroTelefone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tituloInfoContato">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtaddTelefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/dicaTelefone"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Celular -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInputAddCadastroCelular"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtInputAddCadastroTelefone">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtaddCelular"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/dicaCelular"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Email -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInputAddEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtInputAddCadastroCelular">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:hint="@string/Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código que realizou e não funcionou? Vejo que seu layout vai ficar bem mais simples se trocar o `RelativeLayout` mais externo por um `LinearLayout` com `orientation="vertical"`, talvez até facilite a forma de adicionar as `Views` dinamicamente.

Comment: Eu tentei isto 
`View view=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.bloco_cardview, null);`

`RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_contato);
layout.addView(view);
`

Comment: Refiz o código utilizando um `LinearLayout`como o layout mais externo como você disse, funcionou, agora só preciso descobrir como recuperar os dados inseridos nos edittext :)

Comment: Nesse caso é só guardar a referência

Comment: Estou vendo como fazer isso neste exato momento, se tiver alguma dica agradeço.

Comment: Acho que consegui, cada vez que adiciono um novo bloco, adiciono os edittexts dele em um `ArrayList<EditText>`, depois para receber o valor recupero pelo ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Após receber uma grande ajuda do usuário [Wakin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6436/wakim), ele me sugeriu mudar meu layout superior por um `RelativeLayout`, o que funcionou muito bem e depois para recuperar os valores dos EditText criei um ArrayList onde a cada clique eu adicionava o EditText à lista. Por fim para recuperar o valor do EditText foi simplesmente chamar o objeto dentro da lista.

O código final ficou da seguinte forma:

```
// Lista que recebe o editText
List<EditText> alleds = new ArrayList<EditText>;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // View que recebeu o layout do meu cardview
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout,null);

    // LinearLayout superior ao meu cardview que recebeu o layout
    linearLayout.addView(view);

    // Exemplo de um dos EditTexts do cardView
    EditText edtCelular = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtAddCelular);

    // Adicionando o editText à lista
    alleds.add(edtCelular);

    //Exibindo o valor do campo em um Toast
    Toast.makeText(this,alleds.get(0).getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```